# fabricjs i-text cursor not working properly after load json

Tags: javascript, json, fabricjs

fabricjs i-text cursor is working well when I made just in a new window. 
But after loading the saved json it is not working well.
I am using **league_gothic** font.

please see following picture with wrong cursor(3rd character)
[image]

Saving code

```
savejson = JSON.stringify(canvas.fabric.toJSON())
```

Loading Code

```
canvas.fabric.loadFromJSON(loadjson, function(){
...
}
```

UPDATE: I have seen that i-text object using console.log and found cursoroffsetCache variable.  But there's no idea how I can fix it.
Is there anyone who have met this kind of issue?

Comment: if you provide a full JSON i can make a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually fault of a non loaded font on the canvas.
You should be sure that the font is loaded before using it.
If not the canvas will use a similar font ( arial? ) it will measure the text with that wrong font and you will keep wrong measurement for it.

You have 2 way to solve it:

1) use a proper font loader like https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader is easy, small and works good.
On the callback of the load, load your JSON.

less accurate:

2) after loaded from JSON, with a timeout of 1 or 2 seconds, delete `fabric.charWidthsCache` so that the wrong measurements are deleted.
Set `_forceClearCache` for your text objects to true so that a new measurement is triggered ( and the font has finished loading by that time ), request a renderAll again.